# Entire System corrupted due to .exe files flooded in the system

Tags: 11.04, system, data-recovery

I have been using Ubuntu11.04 for last 3-4 months. Few day ago, I installed wine1.4 to run .exe files on my system. Now a virus is flooded in the entire system which creates a .exe file in each & every folder. And I am unable to view pdf files, .doc documents not even C programs. All the files are corrupted. I am about to loose all of my data & unfortunately.... quit UBUNTU ... Anyone please let me know how to recover this data...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, get rid of your Wine folder, be careful to backup any data in it before you do this:

`rm -rf ~/.wine`
`rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine`

After that, get rid of all your `.exe` files with:
 <sub>**(You will loose ALL your exe files!)**</sub>

`sudo find / -name "*.exe" -delete`

When finished, reboot, and see if the issue is resolved. If not, issue the command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`

Comment: The `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` should be useless since it has nothing to the with the package management system, else, top notch of answer! :)

Comment: The reconfigure is because we don't now what was corrupted exactly.  We don't now either what happened with the files mentioned by the user.

Comment: kk, makes sense. Even though I would be really amazed if the .exe files actually did anything to any system files. These kind of virus are normally targeted at modifying specific Windows system files and just replicating themselves.

Comment: You would probably also have to deal with the issue that he cannot open pdf files, that is due to some registered application in `~/.local/share/applications/wine`. If the user if removing `~/.wine` I would go ahead and make sure that that one is also gone.

Comment: thanks a lot u both... but after trying "sudo find / * | grep ".exe$" | sudo xargs rm -rf" I'm getting following error message.. what is it. Have I made a mistake there..
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: I've edited the answer for 2 reasons: `find` command was probably not going to work with a lot of matches that way, and Wine programs only have access in your home dir, so it's not necessary to remove all also valid Mono-`.exe` files on the entire filesystem. (**and then someone reverted my edit**)

Comment: @omjaijagdish keep editing your post with steps you took and errors you got while following the solutions, the more details the better.

Comment: @gertvdijk the edit was fine, just one thing though, Wine maps Z: as the `/` of your system, depending on what was run probably there are files else where, since the user confirms that they are all over his system I am sure we need to include a search also on the root... Can we make it a timed search? Like all files younger than 1 week ago with `.exe` extension?

Comment: I have uninstalled wine using "rm -rf ~/.wine" also deleted .wine folder from home & then tried for "sudo find / * | grep ".exe$" | sudo xargs rm -rf" but the problem remains the same... .exe's in every folder leaving unable to open pdf, .doc documents

Comment: "sudo find / * | grep ".exe$" | sudo xargs rm -rf" is not working at all... here is the error message.. xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: Ok, rolled back...

Comment: k guys.. hw should I get rid of this nw..? any more valid options..?

Comment: See the revised answer!

Comment: @ Frantique thanks a lot... all .exe's are now deleted.. but i m unable to open pdf files.. getting this error message..  Unable to open document File type Microsoft Help Attribute Definition File (application/octet-stream) is not supported

Comment: @omjaijagdish Open the Properties of a PDF file and go to the "Open With" tab and set  "Documents Viewer" as Default.